# Best practice to handle data from API call and render React components

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am somewhat new to React and looking for best practices for a particular situation within my React/Redux/Firebase PWA. Right now, the part I am concerned with is essentially a wrapper for the Yelp API.

I have a main component that queries the Yelp API when loaded (inside componentDidMount) based on user preferences received elsewhere in the app. This component also queries the API on a form submit with user inputs. It loops thru the data from both, and passes props to a child component. This view looks like a list of all the businesses received from the API. Here's what an example looks like:

```
"businesses": [
    {
      "rating": 4,
      "price": "$",
      "phone": "+14152520800",
      "id": "E8RJkjfdcwgtyoPMjQ_Olg",
      "alias": "four-barrel-coffee-san-francisco",
      "is_closed": false,
      "categories": [
        {
          "alias": "coffee",
          "title": "Coffee & Tea"
        }
      ],
      "review_count": 1738,
      "name": "Four Barrel Coffee",
      "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/four-barrel-coffee-san-francisco",
      "coordinates": {
        "latitude": 37.7670169511878,
        "longitude": -122.42184275
      },
      "image_url": "http://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/MmgtASP3l_t4tPCL1iAsCg/o.jpg",
      "location": {
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "country": "US",
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "state": "CA",
        "address1": "375 Valencia St",
        "zip_code": "94103"
      },
      "distance": 1604.23,
      "transactions": ["pickup", "delivery"]
    },
    // ...
  ],
```

As mentioned before, the main component passes down data to the child component, which renders each single object that list. This child component also creates a Link to another component based on the id of each business. This other component for now is simply the exact same look as one individual child component, just on a different URL. For example, the main component is "/venues" and the individual page for a business would be "/venue/E8RJkjfdcwgtyoPMjQ_Olg". The data is pulled from the Redux state (its a HOC), and filtered out to find that id.

The problem I'm running in to is when I refresh the page while on a businesses's individual page, Redux state is cleared out and hence is unable to render properly with the data. To try and work around this I attempted to have a service worker cache everything it would need, but this does not work. Refreshing ends up just showing the loading page I created, because its not making the call (which is expected - don't want it doing this) and its also not pulling data from the caches.

Is there a better way to accomplish getting data all the way to the individual business component after a refresh? Or a better way to cache the entire page/API response so it will render properly on a refresh?

I suppose I could have it reach out to the API for that specific business but I was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember Yelp API has an endpoint where you can get details of an individual business. That said, you should have a **dynamic** route for your individual business page; e.g. `/businesses/:id`. Then you can access this **query param** in your **route props** and go from there to fetch data for that specific business.

Something like this:

```
class IndividualBusiness extends Component {
  // ...

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchBusinessById(this.props.match.id).then(setState(...))
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

The route would look like something like this:

```
<Route exact path="/businesses/:id" render={(routeProps) => <IndividualBusiness {...routeProps} />}/>
```

But what about when data is already in redux store? Simple, just add the control flow in your `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Gotcha, I had learned dynamic routes is generally the way to handle that situation but I wanted to make sure there wasn't some other way that would be better.

I was trying to avoid making extra calls to the API but I guess that would be the only way to do it

Comment: I mean u can store them in localStorage which has a really basic API to work with. But I’ve never seen anyone do that. They just make the extra fetch call.

Comment: Gotcha, thats fair enough. I actually like is as a class making the call now, get a bit more useful info from the API!

Comment: @Adam not sure what u meant by **class making the fetch call**. U mean the function **fetchBusinessById()**? Just to clarify the **class** is the component. I missed the **extends Component** but just added it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `localStorage`? there's a [redux middleware for it](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage). It looks something like this:

```
import {createStore, compose} from 'redux';
import persist from 'redux-localstorage';

const store = createStore(reducer, compose(...otherMiddleware, persist(['apiResponses'])))
```

That should make the `"apiResponses"` section of your redux state persist through browser reloads.

Comment: Interesting option, I will look into this